# How to click on the button after data paste

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to click on the button after I have pasted a value on a text box. However none of the code I tried seems to work. On the same column there are 2 text boxes and few buttons. I managed to open up a new frame after clicked on the 1st button with the below code:

```
Set the_button_elements = doc.getElementsByTagName("div")
For Each button_element In the_button_elements
    If button_element.getAttribute("class") = "pzbtn-mid" Then
        button_element.Click
        Exit For
    End If
    Next button_element
```

I have tried by changing the tag name and attribution and also the below code but it still doesn't work:

```
doc.querySelectorAll("[type=button]").item(3).Click
```

Below is the element for the 1st button which work with the above code:

```
 <button type="button" class="pzhc" id="AcctNumber" 
 disabled="" onclick="this.disabled=true;javascript: LoadAcct();"
 title="Search"> 
<div class="pzbtn-lft">
<div class="pzbtn-rgt">
<div class="pzbtn-mid" data-click="...">
<img class="pzbtn-i">Go</div></div></div></button>
```

Below is the element for the next button which I am trying to find the code to make it work:

```
<button type="button" class="pzhc" id="SearchBtn" 
 disabled="true"onclick="getCaseDetails();"> 
<div class="pzbtn-lft">
<div class="pzbtn-rgt">`enter code here`
<div class="pzbtn-mid">
<img class="pzbtn-i">Search</div></div></div></button>
```

Appreciate someone could guide me by providing me the code that click on the button as the button is still grey out even after the text pasted. However this is the same situation for the 1st code but it still works.

Comment: Element for the button next to the 2nd text box: <button type="button" class="pzhc" id="SearchBtn" disabled="true" onclick="getCaseDetails();"> 
<div class="pzbtn-lft">
<div class="pzbtn-rgt">
<div class="pzbtn-mid">
<img class="pzbtn-i">Search</div></div></div></button>

Comment: I think your question is incomplete. Can you add the full code. Also the link to the site and Screenshots will be helpful in understanding your problem.

Comment: I can't provide the URL as it needed user ID & password to access

Comment: All of the top section of code can be replaced with a single line: _doc.getElementById("AcctNumber").click_

Comment: What do you mean by _I managed to open up a new frame_ ?  Is this a new IE window, a pop-up or something else entirely?

Comment: For the 1st text box, an iframe will open up after I paste in the value and run with  the above code. By the way the code (doc.getElementById("AcctNumber").click) provided doesn't work unless i run it with the code I provided above.

Comment: I find that suprising unless you are actually clicking on a different button from the html you show. The id is the id for the same element. There should be no difference except by id is faster and you have less lines of code.

Comment: With respect to iframe can you grab its src attribute value and .Navigate to it?

Comment: In that column there 2 text box and few buttons. This code (Set the_button_elements = doc.getElementsByTagName("div")
For Each button_element In the_button_elements
    If button_element.getAttribute("class") = "pzbtn-mid" Then
        button_element.Click
        Exit For
    End If
    Next button_element) is working for the 1st button next to the text box but I can't make it work for button next to the 2nd text box. Is there any code that I can use as press enter?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the issue relates to the disabled attribute. If we want to click the button, we should make sure it is enabled status. After clicking the first button or in the textbox change event, you could use the following JavaScript code to enable the Search button:

```
document.getElementById("SearchBtn").disabled = false;
```

You could check the following sample:

```
   <button type="button" class="pzhc" id="AcctNumber"  onclick='this.disabled=true;javascript: alert("Go");  document.getElementById("SearchBtn").disabled = false;'
        title="Search">
    <div class="pzbtn-lft">
        <div class="pzbtn-rgt">
            <div class="pzbtn-mid" data-click="...">
                <img class="pzbtn-i">Go
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</button>

<button type="button" class="pzhc" id="SearchBtn"
       disabled="true" onclick='javascript: alert("Search");'>
    <div class="pzbtn-lft">
        <div class="pzbtn-rgt">
            `enter code here`
            <div class="pzbtn-mid">
                <img class="pzbtn-i">Search
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</button>
```

Then, if I use the following VBA script click the button, it will click the Go button, then, enable the search button and click it:

```
Sub login()

    Const Url$ = "https://dillion132.github.io/vbatestpage.html"

    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie    
        .navigate Url
        ieBusy ie
        .Visible = True
        'Find the related button
        Dim button_go_element As Object, button_search As Object

        Set button_go_element = .document.getElementById("AcctNumber")
        Set button_search = .document.getElementById("SearchBtn")
        button_go_element.Click
        button_search.Click

    End With

End Sub

Sub ieBusy(ie As Object)
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your advice. The codes work like miracle .